# Error connecting to elasticsearch Java CLient API 5.4.3

Tags: elasticsearch, elasticsearch-5, java-client

I'm developping a web application using spring websphere and elasticsearch I want to conenct my java client api with elasticsearch but I got this error thanks for helping

```
[05/01/18 19:54:31:660 WET] 00000054 SystemErr     R ERROR StatusLogger No log4j2 configuration file found. Using default configuration: logging only errors to the console.
    [05/01/18 19:54:33:373 WET] 000000b9 SystemErr     R Exception in thread "elasticsearch[_client_][management][T#1]" java.lang.AbstractMethodError: org/elasticsearch/transport/TcpTransport.connectToChannels(Lorg/elasticsearch/cluster/node/DiscoveryNode;Lorg/elasticsearch/transport/ConnectionProfile;)Lorg/elasticsearch/transport/TcpTransport$NodeChannels;
    [05/01/18 19:54:33:373 WET] 000000b9 SystemErr     R    at org.elasticsearch.transport.TcpTransport.openConnection(TcpTransport.java:534)
    [05/01/18 19:54:33:373 WET] 000000b9 SystemErr     R    at org.elasticsearch.transport.TcpTransport.openConnection(TcpTransport.java:116)
    [05/01/18 19:54:33:373 WET] 000000b9 SystemErr     R    at org.elasticsearch.transport.TransportService.openConnection(TransportService.java:334)
    [05/01/18 19:54:33:373 WET] 000000b9 SystemErr     R    at org.elasticsearch.client.transport.TransportClientNodesService$SniffNodesSampler$1.doRun(TransportClientNodesService.java:507)
    [05/01/18 19:54:33:373 WET] 000000b9 SystemErr     R    at org.elasticsearch.common.util.concurrent.ThreadContext$ContextPreservingAbstractRunnable.doRun(ThreadContext.java:638)
    [05/01/18 19:54:33:373 WET] 000000b9 SystemErr     R    at org.elasticsearch.common.util.concurrent.AbstractRunnable.run(AbstractRunnable.java:37)
    [05/01/18 19:54:33:373 WET] 000000b9 SystemErr     R    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1153)
    [05/01/18 19:54:33:373 WET] 000000b9 SystemErr     R    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628)
    [05/01/18 19:54:33:373 WET] 000000b9 SystemErr     R    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:785)
```

[05/